# How to return multiple types of data in C#

Tags: c#, class, generics, methods, instance

I do return different instances of service depending on a enum in my application:

```
public (????) CurrentService
{
    get
    {
        switch (CurrentServiceEnum)
        {
            case ServiceType.ServiceA:
                return IoC.ServiceA;
            case ServiceType.ServiceB:
                return IoC.ServiceB;
            case ServiceType.ServiceC:
                return IoC.ServiceC;
        }
    }
}
```

Each of that service has it's own implementation of `RemoveAccount` method, taking **different** type argument.

```
internal class ServiceA_AccountDataModel { [..] }
internal class ServiceB_AccountDataModel { [..] }
internal class ServiceC_AccountDataModel { [..] }

public class ServiceA {
    public void RemoveAccount(ServiceA_AccountDataModel model) { [...] }
}
public class ServiceB {
    public void RemoveAccount(ServiceB_AccountDataModel model) { [...] }
}
public class ServiceC { 
    public void RemoveAccount(ServiceC_AccountDataModel model) { [...] }
}
```

What I want to achieve here, is to be able to call a `RemoveAccount` method apart of the current service returned so that while passing the `account` of `ServiceC_AccountDataModel` is should automatically resolve to `IoC.ServiceC`.

```
// account is an instance of ServiceC_AccountDataModel so it should assume that CurrentService is the instance of ServiceC
CurrentService.RemoveAccount(account);
```

Is there a way to achieve something like that in C#?

Comment: [Polymorphism C# Programming Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism) and [Interfaces C# Programming Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/)

Comment: If you know that `account` is of type `ServiceC_AccountDataModel` why don't you just call `IoC.ServiceC.RemoveAccount(account);` ???

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is for all the services to implement a common interface:

```
public interface IAccountRemovalService<T>
{
    void RemoveAccount<T>(T model);
}

public class ServiceA : IAccountRemovalService<ServiceA_AccountDataModel>
{
    public void RemoveAccount<ServiceA_AccountDataModel>(ServiceA_AccountDataModel model) 
    { 
    }
}

public class ServiceB : IAccountRemovalService<ServiceB_AccountDataModel>
{
    public void RemoveAccount<ServiceB_AccountDataModel>(ServiceA_AccountDataModel model) 
    { 
    }
}
```

In order for this to work, you do need there to be something in common between each of your model types, such as a base class like `AccountModelDataBase`:

```
public class ServiceA_AccountDataModel : AccountDataModelBase {}

public class AccountDataModelBase {}
```

Once you've got that, it becomes possible to re-write your `CurrentService` property along these lines:

```
public IAccountRemovalService<AccountDataModelBase> CurrentService
{
    get
    {
        IAccountRemovalService<AccountDataModelBase> returnedValue = null;
        switch (CurrentServiceEnum)
        {
            case ServiceType.ServiceA:
                returnedValue = IoC.ServiceA as IAccountRemovalService<AccountDataModelBase>;
                break;
            case ServiceType.ServiceB:
                returnedValue = IoC.ServiceB as IAccountRemovalService<AccountDataModelBase>;
                break;
            case ServiceType.ServiceC:
                returnedValue = IoC.ServiceC as IAccountRemovalService<AccountDataModelBase>;
                break;
        }
        return returnedValue;
    }
}
```

This does involve quite a few changes to your code, adding the interface and the base class, but it does give you a bit of an advantage as now you can ensure (by virtue of adding new members to IAccountRemovalService) that all your implementations of a service that have the `RemoveAccount` method remain in lock-step with regards to methods that they implement.

One small side note, having the property that you're switching on called `CurrentServiceEnum` doesn't quite sit right because of the `Enum` suffix on it, that'd probably be something to consider removing - but that's just my opnion! =)

Comment: And how would you get the `CurrentService` property to work with this?

Comment: The cast in the last block of code will return null now.

Comment: You also have a redundant generic type specified in the method inside `IAccountRemovalService` that hides the outer type.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. One thing I'm confused about is this line: taking generic type: `public class ServiceA : IAccountRemovalService<ServiceA_AccountDataModel>`. In fact, it can take whatever type and still be working fine: https://pastebin.com/raw/6jmSZRza Why is that?

Comment: @Rusco Because there is no constraint on the generic type, you can use anything. You could change it to `public interface IAccountRemovalService<T> where T : AccountDataModelBase` to restrict it. However, the code in this answer *doesn't work* because it relies on the `IAccountRemovalService` interface being covariant which it isn't.

Comment: Well, it's working "fine" for me except some warnings like `Type parameter 'T' has the same name as the type parameter from outer type IAccountRemovalService<T>`.

Comment: @Rusco Yes, it compiles but the return value of the `CurrentService` is going to be null. For example, instead of `IoC.ServiceA as IAccountRemovalService<AccountDataModelBase>` try a proper cast `(IAccountRemovalService<AccountDataModelBase>)IoC.ServiceA`

Comment: It's not null for me. I don't even need a cast there: https://pastebin.com/pZh90HBg This works without any problems.

Comment: Alright, to wrap everything up in this topic - here is the code I ended up with... https://pastebin.com/6xfvrEru Turned out I don't need any base class there so I used a `object` type for the common type and works fine (base class would remain empty, so it doesn't really make any sense I think). So far so good except annoying warnings in the interface (`Type parameter 'T' has the same name as the type parameter from outer type IAccountRemovalService<T>`). I think this code could be improved.